# Compare string values in different tables using LIKE operator in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, dynamic, string-matching

I have two tables. Each table has the following columns:

```
Address 
City    
ST  
[ZIP Code]
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

The string format in table the "Table_A" is different from the "Table_B"; however, the addresses may still match.

Eg: in the "Table_A" the address is 15 W 34TH ST, but in "Table_B" address is written and plain English as follows: 15 West 34th Street.

I need to do the best to match those addresses across the two tables from the above.

Please

Comment: Address standardization generally requires special purpose software.  This is not a good fit for SQL.

Comment: You should consider doing this in your application code instead.

Comment: I kind of guessed it :) I was thinking of making each address a variable in table  A and wanted to compare it to table B using LIKE. But my tables have not common ID and the number of records is different.

Comment: It all depends on the requirements. There can be many different approaches. If you want to do it on the back end, you can always rig a CLR proc or function.